# How to rename a column name in MySQL through java code by taking the values from a Text Field in Java?

Tags: java, mysql

So I want to rename column name in my MySQL table named `main`.

I want to rename the column name in it. But I want to take the `old name` and the `new name` from two text fields with an underscore between the values entered in the text fields.

Code I used:

```sql
ALTER TABLE main Change COLUMN"+v+"_"+b+""+nename+"_"+lename+"varchar(200);
```

`v` is the variable of the old name's first text field.
`b` is the variable of the old name's second text field.
`nename` is the variable of the new name's first text field.
`lename` is the variable of the new name's second text field.

Comment: Welcome to the community! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```java
String old_col_name = v + "_" + b;
String new_col_name = nename + "_" + lename;
String sql = "ALTER TABLE main RENAME COLUMN " + old_col_name + " TO " + new_col_name;
```

Comment: `String sql = String.format("ALTER TABLE main RENAME COLUMN %s TO %s", old_col_name, new_col_name)`

Comment: String.format() makes code more readable

Comment: The code is not working giving an error.Take a look at it:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-1XofAteafhw3egZWUVRzK7AcgQWlhHu/view?usp=drivesdk (It looks clearer when zoomed in)